# Connect xampp to online MSSQL database via PDO in php

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, xampp

I've installed xampp on my computer.
When I try to connect it tells me

> Error!: could not find driver

When I run my code on my webhost, it works.

Some info:

> XAMPP 3.2.2
>   MSSQL Server 2012

I connect with the following code:

```
define("USER_NAME", "myusername");
define("DATABASE", "mydatabase");
define("PASSWORD", "mypassword");
define("HOST", "myhost");

try{
    $db = new PDO("dblib:host=".HOST.";dbname=".DATABASE, USER_NAME, PASSWORD);
    $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE,PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
}catch(PDOException $exception){
    echo $exception->getMessage();
    exit;
}
```

I've downloaded these files, dropped them in the ext folder and added the following lines to php.ini:

```
extension=php_dblib.dll  
extension=php_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll  
extension=php_pdo_sqlsrv_54_ts.dll
```

Comment: run phpinfo() and check if pdo is enable or not

Comment: PDO is enabled for the following drivers: `mysql, odbc, pgsql, sqlite, sqlsrv`

Comment: use this $db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=YouAddress;Database=YourDatabase", "Username", "Password");

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.php

Comment: Works like a charm thanks ! Any idea why it didn't work with the dblib locally?

Comment: I founded on php.net site

Comment: If it's works then plz vote

Comment: Done, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
$db = new PDO("sqlsrv:Server=YouAddress;Database=YourDatabase", "Username", "Password");
```